# EL Validator cannot run on project a because Validation Builder precedes JBoss Knowledge Base Builder

Tags: eclipse, validation, jakarta-ee, el, jboss-tools

I am woriking on A maven Project. 
the project run very well.
But when I see the marquers I found this problem.

**EL Validator cannot run on project a because Validation Builder precedes JBoss Knowledge Base Builder.**

do you have any idea ??

Answer (score 12):

This is a eclipse project configuration problem. The validation builder is placed before the JBoss Tools Knowledge Base builder which collects the information for the validation builder. The validation builder should be the last one. Go to Project Properties -> JBoss Knowledge Base. Disable JBoss Tools Knowledge Base support there. Apply the changes. Enable JBoss Tools Knowledge Base support again. It will solve this problem.
Please report a bug to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE if you can describe how to create such a broken project.

Answer (score 0):

Alexey's answer didn't work for me.  What I found worked was to delete the project from eclipse and re-import it.